# How to retrieve message history from iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I needs to show messages which are available in history. I mean messages that are present in iphone.

I try from google but no any appropriate help.

Is there no any way to retrieve it from iphone ?

or is there any alternative way ? Please mention that I just need the history of messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean messages as in SMS? If so, the answer is easy: you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Hiren,

As per my knowledge we can find this data from iphone database. This is a sqlite database which includes all the information regarding the sms saved in application.

I have no idea how to fetch that database from iphone application.

Thanks